# Route equivalent in Next.js with render feature for nested component routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I am fairly new to Next.js and till now been having an awesome experience with it.
However, I am confused how to do equivalent of the below code in Next.js
Mainly all these are client side routes and render nested components in the user page.

`${currentPath}` is `/user` in the below snippet.

```
    <div>
     <UserNavbar/>
     <SecondaryNavbar/>
      <div>
        <Route path={`${currentPath}/dashboard`} exact
         render={() => <Dashboard {...this.props}/>} />
        <Route path={`${currentPath}/listings`} exact
         render={() => <Listings {...this.props}/>} />
        <Route path={`${currentPath}/listings/new`} exact
         render={() => <AddNewListing {...this.props}/>} />
        <Route path={`${currentPath}/account`} exact
         render={() => <Account {...this.props} /> } />
     </div>
    </div>
```

Could be that I am completely off-track about this one. I've tried finding help on this in Next.js spectrum chat as well.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One of the solution I can think of is to completely leave routing for Next.js

Just create the following folder structure

```
pages/
  user/
    account.js
    dashboard.js
    listings.js
    // etc...
  user.js
```

Where each route e.g. `/user/account` will be rendered by respective js file e.g. `user/account.js`

**Example `/pages/user.js` file**

```
import Link from 'next/link';

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User page</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Go to <Link href="/user/account">account</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**`/pages/user/account.js`**

```
export default () => {
  return <div>account</div>;
};
```

I might be missing what you want to implement exactly but hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for sharing an example. However, my question is more inline with rendering components instead of pages. Imagine you have a `user` page and have to render a tab-navigator within it on the client side. Where-in every tab should also reflect in the url.

For example: /user/account , /user/dashboard etc.

What I am looking for is a render equivalent of react-router in Next.js
For now, I have solved my problem by using `as` property from `next/link`
and by redirecting to `user` page on every tab change.

Example: <Link href="user" as="/user/account" >

Comment: @ashish.gd did you find your answer as to how to change the rendered component based on the path?

Comment: @rugy not really, I went ahead with the `as` option I mentioned above. Haven't really done much work in Next since this project.